# Vuejs how to display Div if an array contains a value

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to display images based on the contents of an array.

I'm building a menu like page for a cafeteria. I need to display each items allergens but can't figure out how to use v-if to display a div containing the corresponding allergen image if it's contained in the allergens array. I'm pulling all of the data from an api that I don't have control over. This is a sample of what the api returns.

```
{
"location_id": "Cannon",
"serve_date": "20200204",
"meal_name": "BREAKFAST",
"category": "Euro Kitchen",
"name": "Chorizo & Egg Chilaquiles",
"serving_size": "1 each (229.50g)",
"nutrients": [
{
"name": "Calories",
"measurement": "kcal",
"amount": 477.2
},
{
"name": "Total Fat",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 30.73
},
{
"name": "Saturated Fat",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 12.55
},
{
"name": "Trans Fat",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 0
},
{
"name": "Cholesterol",
"measurement": "mg",
"amount": 433.25
},
{
"name": "Sodium",
"measurement": "mg",
"amount": 900.56
},
{
"name": "Carbohydrates",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 23.57
},
{
"name": "Total Fiber",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 2.2
},
{
"name": "Total Sugars",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 2.25
},
{
"name": "Protein",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 25.22
},
{
"name": "Vitamin A",
"measurement": "iu",
"amount": 1310.47
},
{
"name": "Vitamin C",
"measurement": "mg",
"amount": 1.68
},
{
"name": "Calcium",
"measurement": "mg",
"amount": 271.25
},
{
"name": "Iron",
"measurement": "mg",
"amount": 2.85
},
{
"name": "Water",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 3.76
},
{
"name": "Ash",
"measurement": "g",
"amount": 0.05
},
{
"name": "Potassium",
"measurement": "mg",
"amount": 160.63
},
{
"name": null,
"measurement": null,
"amount": 42.87
}
],
"allergens": [
"Milk",
"Egg",
"Corn",
"MSG"
],
"ingredients": "Scrambled Eggs (Liquid Eggs (Whole Eggs; Citric Acid; Water); Cheddar Cheese (Pasteurized Milk; Salt; Enzymes; Annatto); Salt; Black Pepper); Tortilla Chips (Corn Cooked with Lime Water; Water; Cellulose Gum; Guar Gum; Sodium Propionate; Propionic Acid; Sodium Hydroxide; Fumaric Acid; Sorbic; Methyparanen; Propylparaben); Chorizo Sausage (Pork; Vinegar; Water; Chili Peppers; Salt; Paprika; Spices; Oleoresin Paprika; Garlic Powder; Onion Powder; Sugar; Autolyzed Yeast; Oleoresin Capsicum; Natural Flavors; Natural Smoke Flavor); Enchilada Sauce (Tomato Puree; Water; Red Chili Puree; Salt; Chili Pepper; Canola Oil; Onion Powder; Spices; Garlic Puree; Oleoresin Paprika; Pectin; Cornstarch; Natural Flavor; Lemon Juice Concentrate; Citric Acid; Guar Gum; Xanthan Gum; Garlic Powder; Autolyzed Yeast Extract; Locust Bean Gum); Green Onions; Cotija Cheese (Pasteurized Whole Milk; Salt; Rennet; Enzymes; Cellulose)",
"header": false,
"special_diets": [
"Vegetarian"
]
},
```

At the base of this snippet there is a field called allergens. On the website I have corresponding images that match each of these items. For example

img src="./images/Wheat_icon.png"

I want to display this icon if and only if the array contains that allergen.

I tried to do this:

```
<div class="nutrition-allergen-icon" v-if="'displayedContains(egg)'">
                <img class="nutrition-allergen-img" 
                src="./images/Egg_icon.png"></div>

methods: {
displayedContains: function (item) {
    console.log("hit")
    for(allergen in this.displayedItem) { 
      if(allergen == item)
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
}
```

I also tried:

```
computed: {
    displayedContains: function (item) {
        console.log("hit")
        for(allergen in this.displayedItem) { 
          if(allergen == item)
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    }
```

I need it to be a function because the allergen icon for nuts can be displayed if any of a number of different nuts are in the allergen array.

Comment: from where comes `egg` at `v-if="'displayedContains(egg)'"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution but it's a little different than what you're attempting there.

You can use your method to retrieve the image of the allergen instead of checking whether its there or not.

So you'd have something like this in your model:

```js
data() {
    return {
       ...
    }
},
methods: {
    getAllergenImage(allergen) {
        switch (allergen) {
            case 'Egg':
                return 'Egg_icon.jpg';
            case 'Milk':
                return 'Milk_icon.jpg';
        }
    }
}
```

or if you have control over the name of the image icons, you can just name them so that the switch statement isn't needed:

```js
methods: {
    getAllergenImage(allergen) {
       return `${allergen}_icon.jpg`;
    }
}
```

Then when you get to the part of your app where you need to display the images for the allergens, just iterate over the allergen array and look-up the corresponding image using your new method:

```html
<div class="nutrition-allergen-icon" v-for="allergen in allergens">
    <img class="nutrition-allergen-img" :src="'./images/' + getAllergenImage(allergen)">
</div>
```

Here's a codepen of a working example:

https://codepen.io/kburlz/pen/PoqYOrQ

Comment: I ended up going with this solution because I needed a little more control for default cases. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What if you used an object to store the relationship between allergen strings and their corresponding images? Something like this:

```js
  allergenLookup: {
      Egg: 'egg_image.png',
      Milk: 'milk_image.png',
      Corn: 'corn_image.png',
      Peanut: 'nut_image.png',
      Walnut: 'nut_image.png',
      Almond: 'nut_image.png',
      MSG: 'msg_image.png'
      ...
  },
```

That way you can loop through the allergens and display the correct image like this:

```html
<div class="nutrition-allergen-icon" v-for="allergen in foodItem.allergens">
  <img class="nutrition-allergen-img" :src="'./images/' + allergenLookup[allergen]">
</div>
```

Also, a very fake example, with text instead of images here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/6x9bonh4/

Comment: Thank you for the timely response, worked like a champ!

Answer (score -1):

I think that your snippet isn't clearly, however u can apply this logic to do conditional rendering:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      ingredients: [
        { name: 'foo' },
        { name: 'egg' },
        { name: 'bar' }
      ],
      allergens: [
        "Milk",
        "Egg",
        "Corn",
        "MSG"
      ],
      allergensLowerCase: []
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.allergensLowerCase = this.allergens.map(allergen => allergen.toLowerCase());
  },

  methods: {
    displayedContains (item) {
      const itemLowerCase = item.toLowerCase()
      return this.allergensLowerCase.includes(itemLowerCase) // returns true | false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template 
    v-for="ingredient in ingredients"
  >
    <div
      v-if="displayedContains(ingredient.name)"
      class="nutrition-allergen-icon"
    >
      {{ ingredient.name }}
      <img 
        class="nutrition-allergen-img" 
        src="./images/Egg_icon.png"
      >
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

or using computed properties to filter:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      ingredients: [
        { name: 'foo' },
        { name: 'egg' },
        { name: 'bar' },
      ],
      allergens: [
        "Milk",
        "Egg",
        "Corn",
        "MSG"
      ],
      allergensLowerCase: []
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.allergensLowerCase = this.allergens.map(allergen => allergen.toLowerCase());
  },

  computed: {
    filteredIngredients() {
      return this.ingredients.filter(ingredient => this.allergensLowerCase.includes(ingredient.name.toLowerCase()))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="(ingredient, index) in filteredIngredients" :key="index"
    class="nutrition-allergen-icon"
  >
    {{ ingredient.name }}
    <img 
      class="nutrition-allergen-img" 
      src="./images/Egg_icon.png"
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

and for the `src` image:

```
src="`./images/${ingredient.name}_icon.png`"
```